# Read request content in JSON form from OperationContext in C#

Tags: c#, json, wcf, operationcontext, weboperationcontext

I have created WCF RESTful service as below:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
UriTemplate = "/Customer/{customerID}/profile")]
string PutCustomerProfileData(string customerID);
```

I'm debugging this using **Postman** and passing **JSON** data in BODY as below:

> {     "customerID":"RC0064211",   "TermsAgreed":"true" }

```
public string PutCustomerProfileData(string customerID)
{
    Message requestMessage = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage;
}
```

What it returns in RequestMessage is as below:

```
{<root type="object">
  <customerID type="string">RC0064211</customerID>
  <TermsAgreed type="string">true</TermsAgreed>
</root>}
```

I want this request body in JSON form. Can I have it? If not what is the other way that I can create JSON string for mentioned `RequestMessage`?

Comment: You could try adding an `Accept: application/json` header in Postman. But to be honest that can't be your actual code for `PutCustomerProfileData` - what are you returning?

Comment: I have already set that header too, but not helping me anyway. And for `PutCustomerProfileData`, it will return JSON format only with proper message.

Comment: `PutCustomerProfileData` is obviously not returning JSON though, given the XML you're seeing. Can you paste the full code of `PutCustomerProfileData` (or at least everything relevant to constructing the output string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with the `DataContract` and `DataMember` and it worked for me.

Below is the sample code:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/Customer/{customerID}/verification")]
    string PutCustomerVerificationData(string customerID, CustomerVerification customerVerification);
}

[DataContract]
public class CustomerVerification
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have converted that DataContract to the JSON string and used it further as below:

```
public string PutCustomerVerificationData(string customerID, CustomerVerification customerVerification)
{
      JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      string requestBody = js.Serialize(customerVerification);
      string serviceResponse = bllCustomerDetails.PutCustomerVerificationData(customerID, requestBody).Replace("\"", "'");
      return serviceResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **[DataMember]** over the member variables which you want to convert into JSON.

Comment: Can you provide some code sample, if possible, as I am not aware that how to work with `DataMember`.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0d4efc/data-contract-in-wcf/ - is it the same you are referencing to?

Comment: No I got this issue around 6 months back so [DataMember] fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did not fully understand the problem but as a recommendation I might suggest;

You should design your WebConfig for Json like this;

```
    <services>
  <service name="Your Service Name"

    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="YourProjectName">

    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" />

             </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttp">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

And your data member should like this(just example);

```
   [DataContract]
public class Customer
{
   [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int customerID { get; set; }

}
```

Also, you can try on your webservice on **Fiddler 4** and you can request and response as JSON or what you want.